# Write qUnit output to file via Grunt

Tags: node.js, junit, gruntjs, npm, qunit

I need to be able to report qUnit tests to a file so my build server can parse them.

I'm using qUnit (grunt-contrib-qunit) through Grunt along with the jUnit reporter found [here](https://github.com/jquery/qunit-reporter-junit).

I can get the report to write to the log just as it states but I'm having trouble getting it into a file.  I've tried qunit callbacks in my gruntfile but none of them seem to get the xml info.  I also tried to simply redirect stdout but it (of course) printed all of the non-xml command-line stuff along with the xml.

In short, I've got the XML echoing properly in the console.log statement.  I just need to get this to a file somehow.  Either through Grunt, phantomjs, or any other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're running QUnit tests from Grunt, then you have the full power of Node at your disposal. I've never used that JUnit plugin, but if it just gives you callback in your QUnit HTML file, then you would need a browser solution (even if that is phantomjs).

[Phantom uses QtWebKit](http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html), which has implemented the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) so you could implement a solution using that from JUnit's callback, but, of course, that would fail if you run the tests in certain other browsers (namely IE9 or under). Here's how that might look (no guarantees on this being exact, I have not run it):

```
QUnit.jUnitReport = function(report) {
  function onInitFs(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('qunit_report.xml', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) { /* if you need it */ };
        fileWriter.onerror = function(e) { /* if you need it */ };

        var blob = new Blob([report.xml], {type: 'application/xml'});
        fileWriter.write(blob);
      }, someErrorHandlerFunction);

    }, someErrorHandlerFunction);
  }
  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, someErrorHandlerFunction);
}
```

And again, if you need to do something to write the file in IE9 or under (or some mobile browsers) you'll need another solution, like kicking off an ajax request to upload the data to a server that stores the file. You could even run that "server" from within Grunt and have Node write the file.

Comment: I think your logic is sound with the file system API but I just couldn't make phantom recognize the method.

Comment: Sorry - the comment window timed out.

**Edit:**

I think your logic is sound with the file system API but I just couldn't get grunt to complete the qunit task successfully.

I did, however, have quite the "aha" moment after reading your last sentence about the "server" initiated from Grunt.  I had just read about that earlier today and had completely forgotten about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, sorry this solution wasn't what worked for you, but hopefully you got something going! For those others reading, the "server" I was talking about was a simple Node `grunt-contrib-connect` server with a basic callback to handle data upload and saving it to a file.